# Ways to go from A to B(proof)

Tags: combinatorics

We know that the ways to go from A to B in a $m×n$ rectangle is $(m+n)!/m!n!$ I want a proof for this formula.(the way should be the shortest.

**My Attempt**:There is a counting way that may help us.
[image]

Every point is calculated by the sum of two adjacent points.

Comment: Presumably you require that each step either takes you up or to the right?  If so then there are $m$ left steps to take and $n$ up steps...the order doesn't matter so it's just a question of where you put the up steps amongst the $n=m$ total so....

Comment: It means the shortest way I wrote that In the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lattice paths and Catalan Numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321192/lattice-paths-and-catalan-numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When considering the possible paths,we say "Up, right, up, right...".
Using "u" and "r" . We can write out a path
$$\underbrace{r,r,r,\ldots ,r}_{m}\,\,\underbrace{u,u,u,\ldots ,u}_{n}$$ 
so there are $\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}$ codes or paths..

Answer (score 0):

See

[Lattice paths and Catalan Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321192/lattice-paths-and-catalan-numbers?lq=1)

or

[How can I find the number of the shortest paths between two points on a 2D lattice grid?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103470/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-the-shortest-paths-between-two-points-on-a-2d-latti?lq=1)

or

[Lattice Paths Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70068/lattice-paths-question?rq=1)

or google for "Counting Paths on a Grid" to find other links, even some videos.